# How to set RefreshPolicy for Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.x

Tags: spring, spring-boot, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch

I have a repository created by extending ElasticsearchRepository to add few methods and I have set the RefreshPolicy to WAIT_UNTIL to avoid extra calls to elasticsearch /_refresh API but I have noticed that calls are still being made whenever repository.save() or repository.deleteByIdentifier1() is getting called.

How do I stop refresh calls from happening from any of the repository method calls without overriding and defining the method myself? From the spring documentation ([Spring Data Elasticsearch documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#elasticsearch-migration-guide-4.1-4.2.breaking-changes.refresh-policy.behaviour)) I could see that the repositories should be using the provided RefreshPolicy if it is set.

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository<MyModel, String> {
    Optional<MyModel> findByIdentifier1(String identifier1);
    void deleteByIdentifier1(String identifier1);
}
```

Elasticsearch template and HLRC config:

```
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient buildClient() {
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY,
                new UsernamePasswordCredentials(properties.getUsername(), properties.getPassword()));

        RestClientBuilder restclientbuilder = RestClient
                .builder(new HttpHost(properties.getHost(), properties.getPort(), properties.getProtocol()));

        restclientbuilder.setHttpClientConfigCallback(httpClientBuilder -> httpClientBuilder.disableAuthCaching()
                .setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider));

        return new RestHighLevelClient(restclientbuilder);

    }

    @Bean(name = "elasticsearchTemplate")
    public ElasticsearchRestTemplate template(RestHighLevelClient client) {
        ElasticsearchRestTemplate template = new ElasticsearchRestTemplate(client);
        template.setRefreshPolicy(org.springframework.data.elasticsearch.core.RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL);
        return template;
    }

    @Bean
    RefreshPolicy refreshPolicy() {
        return RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL;
    }
```

**Dependencies**

- spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch 2.7.12
- spring-data-elasticsearch 4.4.12
- elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client
  7.17.3

Answer (score 0):

If you configure Spring Data Elasticsearch like described in the documentation (https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/4.4.12/reference/html/#elasticsearch.clients.rest), you do not use `@Bean` functions, you rather override the corresponding function from configuration base class. With this little part of code I cannot judge if the `ElasticsearchRestTemplate` you provide is used in the repository calls.

> but I have noticed that calls are still being made

what calls? Explicit refresh calls to Elasticsearch? It's hard to judge what the problem is without a runnable reproducer (be aware that 4.4 is out of maintenance now).

**Edit 29.05.2023:**

Just tried with the Boot 2.7.12 (Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.12) and an Elasticsearch 7.17.1 instance and the following configuration class:

```java
@Configuration
public class RestClientConfig extends AbstractElasticsearchConfiguration {

    @Override
    @Bean
    public RestHighLevelClient elasticsearchClient() {

        ClientConfiguration clientConfiguration = ClientConfiguration.builder() //
                .connectedTo("localhost:9200") //
                .withBasicAuth("elastic", "XXXXXXX") //
                .withProxy("localhost:8080")                     // <== intercepting proxy to check the traffic
                .build();

        return RestClients.create(clientConfiguration).rest();
    }

    @Override
    protected RefreshPolicy refreshPolicy() {
        return RefreshPolicy.WAIT_UNTIL;
    }

}
```

No problems to see, the calls visible in the proxy show the correct refresh value being passed in the requests and no additional refresh calls:

[image]

Comment: Hi @P.J.Meisch, thanks for taking the time to check this.
I have also tried configuring as per the documentation : https://pastebin.com/WwkvZ2e5

Comment: Still the RefreshPolicy is not working.

Yes, by calls I meant explicit calls to the _refresh api after each delete or save operation.
Logs after calling repository.deleteByIdentifier1() : https://pastebin.com/mH79mnDC